# Error setting java class as object in MainActivity android studio -- cannot resolve symbol ""

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a beginner and I have been following several tutorials in order to parse JSON.  I am just about to compile and try to run for the first time but when I tried to make an object of my java class and have the process run when the button "click" is triggered, I get an error stating " Cannot resolve symbol "fetchData" "

```js
package com.example.h.arbitrage;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button click;
    public static TextView data;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        click = findViewById(R.id.button);
        data = findViewById(R.id.fetcheddata);

        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fetchData process = new fetchData();
                ((fetchData) process).execute();


            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm also including the code for fetchData.java in case there's something in there that's causing this.

I've looked all over for the answer and it might be very obvious but I don't even have the terminology to properly research this...

```js
import android.net.UrlQuerySanitizer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.example.h.arbitrage.MainActivity;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    String data = "";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line ="";
            while(line != null){
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        MainActivity.data.setText(this.data);

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why are you casting? That class is extending an AsyncTask. Try with new fetchdata.execute()

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm casting but I am sure that "fetchdata" isn't being recognized.  It gives me this error cannot resolve symbol.  It's not picking up that fetchdata is a class, it seems...

Comment: you haven't imported fetchData class

Comment: Auto import is activated, but I also tried to "optimize Imports" using the "ctrl option O" keymapping on mac.  This did not work, however, instead I get a popup stating, "unused imports not found."  I've been looking for another way to import but haven't found anything.